# not able to pull stable rvm version

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I am trying to install ruby and rails using RVM but unable to install RVM it self 
i tried "sudo bash < <(curl -sk https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)" it says 
Successfully checked out branch ''
then Nothing will happen,i think its not able find the stable release branch.

even i tried pull latest branch by using

"sudo curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm -o rvm-installer ; chmod +x rvm-installer ; ./rvm-installer --version latest"

it is also giving error like 
"% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file /usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm-1.6.32.tar.gz
  1  832k    1 16151    0     0   6697      0  0:02:07  0:00:02  0:02:05  7764
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16151)

ERROR: Failed to download https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-1.6.32.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm-1.6.32.tar.gz using 'curl', error code (0)
"
can anyone please help me installing rvm

I am using ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a permission problem there. It's best if you use `su` (or `sudo su`) to become root, and then run the commands **in the root shell** from there, using `sudo` like you're doing might not work correctly.

**Edit**:

To install without root privileges **do not use sudo**:

```
> cd $HOME
> bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

See the full installation instructions here:
http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Comment: it will create rvm installtion folder under /user/lcoal/bin is it possible to create folder under current user say /{username}/.rvm

Comment: @user - Yes. Do **not** run as root and it will use your user folder automatically.

Comment: how do i install rvm without administrator privilege,i am using sudo to run command so that current login user is elevated to administrator,please explain me step step if it is possible to install without administrator privilege,let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: @user - See my edit. Read the rvm installation instructions carefully, they should explain the whole process.

Comment: i just figured out i sitting behind proxy and my git port is closed,since script is using git protocal its throwing error,do you have any solution for this ?